# Spark custom estimator access to Param[T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am building a custom estimator for spark. Unfortunately, there seems to be something wrong in how I access `Param[T]` default params for the estimator. Here is a minimal example which compares a `Transformer` with an `Estimator`. The Estimator which has access to the same parameter

```
trait PreprocessingParam2s extends Params {
  final val isInList = new Param[Array[String]](this, "isInList", "list of isInList items")
}
```

is called like

```
new ExampleEstimator().setIsInList(Array("def", "ABC")).fit(dates).transform(dates).show
```

In order to perform

```
dataset
      .withColumn("isInList", when('ISO isin ($(isInList): _*), 1).otherwise(0))
```

But unlike the `Transformer` which works fine, the `Estimator` fails with `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Failed to find a default value for isInList`

https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/218683c6b0f91bc76f71cb652cd746b8 or https://github.com/geoHeil/sparkEstimatorProblem (including build.sbt file to easier reproduce the problem)

What is wrong here?

## edit

I am using spark 2.0.2.

As @t-gawęda points out the error can be fixed when setting default parameters. But this should not be necessary as I call new `ExampleEstimator().setIsInList(Array("def", "ABC"))`. So why is the parameter not set?

If I set default parameters they are used as a fallback. But this is not the semantics I want to achieve. Instead of the correct output (of the `Transformer`)

```
+----------+---+--------+
|     dates|ISO|isInList|
+----------+---+--------+
|2016-01-01|ABC|       1|
|2016-01-02|ABC|       1|
|2016-01-03|POL|       0|
|2016-01-04|ABC|       1|
|2016-01-05|POL|       0|
|2016-01-06|ABC|       1|
|2016-01-07|POL|       0|
|2016-01-08|ABC|       1|
|2016-01-09|def|       1|
|2016-01-10|ABC|       1|
+----------+---+--------+

+--------+                                                                      
|isInList|
+--------+
|       1|
|       0|
+--------+
```

I get

```
+----------+---+--------+
|     dates|ISO|isInList|
+----------+---+--------+
|2016-01-01|ABC|       0|
|2016-01-02|ABC|       0|
|2016-01-03|POL|       0|
|2016-01-04|ABC|       0|
|2016-01-05|POL|       0|
|2016-01-06|ABC|       0|
|2016-01-07|POL|       0|
|2016-01-08|ABC|       0|
|2016-01-09|def|       0|
|2016-01-10|ABC|       0|
+----------+---+--------+

+--------+
|isInList|
+--------+
|       0|
+--------+
```

Where clearly the wrong e.g. only default parameters were used. What is wrong with my approach of storing the parameters?
See a working example https://github.com/geoHeil/sparkEstimatorProblem which is setting default parameters.

Comment: Here is code with parameter with the same type: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L436

Comment: @T.Gawęda this sounds good, but unfortunately is not yet clear to me. Please, could you explain this a bit more. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding getter and setDefault in your Parameter:

```
trait PreprocessingParam2s extends Params {
  final val isInList = new Param[Array[String]](this, "isInList", "list of isInList items")

 setDefault(isInList, /* here put default value */)

  /** @group getParam */
  final def getIsInList: Array[String] = $(isInList)
}
```

Why?

Look how params map is created:

```
lazy val params: Array[Param[_]] = {
    val methods = this.getClass.getMethods
    methods.filter { m =>
        Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers) &&
          classOf[Param[_]].isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType) &&
          m.getParameterTypes.isEmpty
      }.sortBy(_.getName)
      .map(m => m.invoke(this).asInstanceOf[Param[_]])
}
```

Spark scans all methods in class and searches methods with:

- public modifier
- no parameters
- there return type is subtype of Param

Spark launches these methods and put values into parameters map. When you read parameter value,  then Spark looks at this map, instead of executing getters

Full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc0ddc270aa316d6985b0772a32e7495)
Explanation: in model you must have :

```
def setIsInList(value : Array[String]): this.type = {
    set(isInList, value)
    this
  }
```

and in fit method of estimator:

```
override def fit(dataset: Dataset[_]): ExampleTransModel = new ExampleTransModel(uid, 1.0).setIsInList($(this.isInList))
```

After creating model, you was not copying value of parameter to model object - that's why it was always empty when evaluating model

Comment: Thanks a lot. here is the fixed code https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/d4e123a6d8fea073591d666379075724 please could you explain why a setDefault / getter is required? For me setting the default value is enough to fix the problem.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Please see update :) Spark caches parameters data

Comment: @GeorgHeiler it's not mandatory, but if you don't set any default value, the code will fail when user will not provide any value

Comment: I see. That is what I expected. However, I do set the isInList parameter value and if I do not set a default value I receive aforementioned error.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler strange, but maybe I missed something. If you put other value than default, is it working with this value? Or taking always default value? I will debug code if it's taking only default value, but shouldn't

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately, you are right. I can only see a single value e.g. the default value. Why didn't spark pick up the parameters in the first place (https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/218683c6b0f91bc76f71cb652cd746b8) when set like `new ExampleEstimator().setIsInList(Array("def", "ABC"))`?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I will check it in a moment

Comment: This is my result: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/fe82d7c1384953b7d2eeb851a95f17b0

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I was looking at it, but didn't find yet. Don't worry, I remember, but also have some time constraints and didn't manage to fix it :/

Comment: No problem. Meanwhile I tried to debug it a bit more and found out that the set method is called (correctly), but as soon as I leave its context the parameter is no longer available to the estimator.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Got it! Here is code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc0ddc270aa316d6985b0772a32e7495 Later I will explain it

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really looking forward for insights to this problem.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I've already edited answer. We was not copying parameter value from estimator to model. I tested it now and results are as you have written

Comment: But shouldn't the parameters be handled via defaultCopy?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can use `copyValues` method, for example `CountVectorizer.scala` uses it. Parameters are not copied by default if you will not do it manually or by one of built-in functions

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for this great explanation.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler No problem :)